# Use LitJson and Json file served from a URL in place of local Json file

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, webrequest, litjson

Needing help with a json (LitJson) issue.
I am trying to read a json file from the web in the same way as I am able to read a local json file.

the way I read the local file is like this

```
public JsonData itemData;
itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Art_.json"));
```

when I debug `itemData` I get back `JsonData array` in the console.

I am successfully reading the json file from the web with this:

```
UnityWebRequest webjson = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://somewebsite.com/Art_.json");
```

when I debug `webjson` i get back the entire json file in the console.

I am not sure how the json is being parsed differently, and why I can not replace the locally served json data with the json data being served from the url.

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: I cast like this:

    `var jsonweb = webjson;
       
     itemData = JsonMapper.ToJson(jsonweb);

     Debug.Log(itemData);`

And now I am getting back the Json data in the console but with many other pieces of information and numbers, and then the Json at the end.

Comment: Well at least now you know why it wasnt working. Whats the other information

Comment: So, it is possible that i need to use `Trim()` to trim the json file. 
If I do `itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(webjson.downloadHandler.text.Trim());`
I receive the error `JsonException: Invalid character '' in input string`

Comment: You’d need to show the data you’re getting back for anyone to answer

Comment: at the moment I get no data back if I use `  itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(webjson.downloadHandler.text.Trim());`

Comment: I get the same error, `JsonException: Invalid character '' in input string`

Comment: As I said you need to show us the whole text you are getting back in that string..